# Ошибка Notice: Undefined index: Price

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
$query ="SELECT AVG(Price) FROM `products` WHERE Manufacturer=2";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $myrow['Price'] . "<br>\n"; // line 15
}
```

Нужно вывести среднюю цену товара у данного производителя

Получаю почему-то ошибку

**Notice: Undefined index: Price in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php on line 15**

Comment: потому что написав в запросе `AVG(Price)` оно и выбирается ровно с таким же именем, которое указано в выборке..... а значит нужно в *PHP* либо писать `echo $myrow['AVG(Price)']`.....либо  чтоб этого не было надо в запросе писать `SELECT AVG(Price) as Price.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка потому, что написав в запросе `AVG(Price)` оно и выбирается ровно с таким же именем, которое указано в выборке. Это значит, что нужно либо в *PHP* коде  писать

```
echo $myrow['AVG(Price)'];
```

либо, чтобы такого имени не было, надо в запросе писать через [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

```
SELECT AVG(Price) as Price.....
```